# unexpected behavior when adding a text input with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a page with a div, and if it's clicked upon then a text input box should appear.

Here's a minimal code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="d1">a</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $( document ).on( "click", "#d1", function( e ){
            $( this ).html( "<input type='text'>" );
    } );       
} );
</script>
```

The problem is that although the text input box appears, no chars are shown there.

However, if I use:

```
$( this ).replaceWith( "<input type='text'>" );
```

it works as expected.

Also, it works as expected if I'm adding the html to another element, for example

```
$("#some_other_element").html( "<input type='text'>" );
```

Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: `on( "click", "#d1"`, what is `"#d1"`, i don't think thats proper binding...

Comment: The characters are not appearing because the input has no value.

Comment: @NoobEditor It looked weird to me too, but I just tried it in the console and it works. His listener works on the id d1. This is actually a good way to set up event listeners because it will work on elements that haven't been added to the DOM yet. If an event listener is declared directly targeting #d1 and #d1 didn't exist yet, then when #d1 is created the event listener will not apply to it unless it is re-executed... but $(document) always exists and can always be clicked on so every time you click anywhere it will check if it is the element #d1 and do something if it is.

Comment: @AllTheTime : 1 new thing learnt today fella...thanks! :D

Comment: `no chars are shown there` where in text box? or you mean the **a** which is inside `<div id="d1">a</div>`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers - I'll try to clarify. Initially there's a div element shown which contains just the char "a". When this div is clicked upon its content (the 'a' char) is replaced by a text input box. However, when I'm typing in that box, the inputted chars aren't shown.

Answer (score 0):

change to this:

```
$( this ).html("<input type='text' value='"+$(this).text().trim()+"'>");
```

Comment: It might be the right answer, but could you explain why the OP should change the line.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    $( document ).on( "click.yourEventName", "#d1", function( e ){
            var $this = $(this);
            var text = $this.text();
            $this.html( $("<input>", {type: "text"}).val(text) );                      
            $(document).off(".yourEventName");
    } );
  
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="d1">a</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but none actually answered my question. Why  when using .html() on the clicked-upon element produces an input text which doesnt show the chars, while .replaceWith() works as expcted. Also, when using .html() on another element it works as expected.